# Как вернуть удаленные компоненты в Windows Phone Framework?

Tags: c#, framework, silverlight, windows-phone-7, коллекции

Суть в том, что из многих компонентов в WinPhone Framework зачем-то удалили целые куски.
Например, из `System.Collections.Generic` выкинут `SortedSet` (очевидно в Microsoft считают, что он там не нужен).

Аналогичная ситуация по-моему с Bitmap, но там хотя бы можно заменить на `WriteableBitmap`.

Собственно вопрос: как можно впихнуть всю эту радость обратно. Ведь эти типы определенно не зависят от самой платформы, просто видимо желание левой пятки Microsoft обрезать фреймворк (зачем?).

Я вижу два способа:

1. Создать свой класс и нагло его описать. Сурово, будет работать, только один черт знает, как выглядит source code у
   того же SortedSet. Его можно где-то посмотреть? Пока нагуглить не смог.
2. Впихнуть как нибудь компоненты из .Net framework нормального в WinPhone-проект. Насчет работоспособности этого что-то я не уверен.

Еще есть пояснения, комментарии, предложения?

Очень хотелось бы, чтобы кто-нибудь пояснил, можно ли найти исходный код для классов из .Net Framework.

---

[update № раз]
Жесть, чем дальше изучаю, тем больше поражаюсь идиотизму ребят из Мелкософта. Ну зачем, зачем надо было выкидывать метод RemoveAll из класса List<T>? С RemoveAll я бы написал лямбда-выражение, тут наколдовал *нечто* с foreach:

```
foreach (someType x in files)
            {
                if (statement)  
                files.Remove(x);
            }
```

Вместо `RemoveAll(x=>y)`. Интересно, это правильно?

З.Ы. Нет. По крайней мере не всегда.

---

**Обновлено 30 октября 2012.**

В общем, если кто-нибудь будет это искать, и, если кому надо, есть сторонняя библиотека "Prism" для Silverlight, где в разделе для Windows Phone есть dll-ка **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll**

Там большинство выкинутого функционала. `RemoveAll` там по крайней мере точно есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Его можно где-то посмотреть?

С помощью .NET Reflector. Но учтите, что там могут быть обращения к неуправляемым библиотекам, отсутствующим в Windows Phone.